# Why is mask not being applied?

Tags: jquery, html, maskedinput

I want to apply mask to an input element when it receives focus with jquery.maskedinput plugin. But the first time it gets focus, the mask is not there. Only when it receives focus the second time, the mask shows up. How can I make the mask to show the first time it gets focus?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aPz2k/)

html:

```
 <input type=text id=a />
    <input type=text id=b />
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#a').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).mask('999');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that the widget uses focus() to add the mask. The element is already focused since you are registering it after the event happened.

The way it should work is to register it when the page is created

```
$(function () {
    $('#a').mask('999')
});
```

BUT if you want to do it onfocus, you need to trigger focus after removing your event so you do not get stuck in a loop.

```
$(function () {
    $('#a').on('focus.first', function () {
        $(this).off("focus.first").mask('999').trigger("focus");
    });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively `.one` could be used instead of `on`/`off` to make it clear that is should be only called once.